Error Report: Launching CVD in AOSP, Failed to connect:No such device
Error Report: Launching CVD in AOSP
Environment Setup
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp$ source build/envsetup.sh
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp$ lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug

Build Configuration
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=VanillaIceCream
PLATFORM_VERSION=VanillaIceCream
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_cf_x86_64_phone
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=silvermont
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-150-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.6-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
BUILD_ID=MAIN
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

Launching CVD
thanhchung@Chung-Computer:/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp$ launch_cvd

Output Logs
09-25 10:17:09.704  5633  5633 I launch_cvd: main.cc:179 Using system_image_dir of: 
===================================================================
NOTICE:

By using this Android Virtual Device, you agree to
Google Terms of Service (https://policies.google.com/terms).
The Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy)
describes how Google handles information generated as you use
Google Services.
===================================================================
Automatically send diagnostic information to Google, such as crash
reports and usage data from this Android Virtual Device. You can
adjust this permission at any time by running
"launch_cvd -report_anonymous_usage_stats=n". (Y/n)?:n    
Reading --config option from: /media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/target/product/vsoc_x86_64/android-info.txt
Launching CVD using --config='phone'.
GPU auto mode: did not detect prerequisites for accelerated rendering support, enabling --gpu_mode=guest_swiftshader.
GPU vhost user auto mode: not needed for --gpu_mode=guest_swiftshader. Not enabling vhost user gpu.
Requested resuming a previous session (the default behavior) but the base images have changed under the overlay, making the overlay incompatible. Wiping the overlay files.
Path for instance UDS: /tmp/cf_avd_1000
The following lines contain useful debugging information:
  Point your browser to https://localhost:8443 to interact with the device.
  Serial console is disabled; use -console=true to enable it.
  Logcat output: /home/thanhchung/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/logcat
  Kernel log: /home/thanhchung/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/kernel.log
  Launcher log: /home/thanhchung/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/logs/launcher.log
  Instance configuration: /home/thanhchung/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/cuttlefish_config.json
  Launcher Build ID: eng.thanhc


...

/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/socket_vsock_proxy
/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/secure_env
/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/log_tee
/media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/process_restarter
Start modem simulator, server_fds: 37, Sim type: normal
Failed to open socket: Connection refused
Server listening on unix:/tmp/cf_avd_1000/cvd-1/grpc_socket/EchoServer.sock
Server listening on unix:/tmp/cf_avd_1000/cvd-1/grpc_socket/CasimirControlServer.sock
Server listening on unix:/tmp/cf_avd_1000/cvd-1/grpc_socket/OpenwrtControlServer.sock
[2024-09-25T03:18:03.462393519+00:00 INFO  crosvm::crosvm::sys::linux] crosvm entering multiprocess mode
[2024-09-25T03:18:03.468936270+00:00 INFO  crosvm::crosvm::sys::linux] crosvm entering multiprocess mode
[2024-09-25T03:18:03.527196995+00:00 INFO  crosvm::crosvm::sys::linux::device_helpers] Trying to attach block device: /home/thanhchung/cuttlefish/instances/cvd-1/ap_overlay.img
[2024-09-25T03:18:03.569833326+00:00 INFO  crosvm::cro

...

...

[2024-09-25T03:18:16.883810070+00:00 INFO  crosvm::crosvm::sys::linux] vcpu requested reset
[2024-09-25T03:18:17.064503417+00:00 INFO  crosvm] exiting with reset
[2024-09-25T03:18:17.086342197+00:00 INFO  crosvm::crosvm::sys::linux] crosvm entering multiprocess mode
crosvm[6189]: libminijail[6189]: compile_file: /media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/usr/share/crosvm/x86_64-linux-gnu/seccomp/serial_device.policy(18): ignored @frequency statement
crosvm[6189]: libminijail[6189]: compile_file: /media/thanhchung/workspace/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/usr/share/crosvm/x86_64-linux-gnu/seccomp/block_device.policy(18): ignored @frequency statement
[2024-09-25T03:18:17.231414870+00:00 INFO  devices::sys::linux::acpi] Listening on acpi_mc_group of acpi_event family
[2024-09-25T03:18:17.237028184+00:00 INFO  x86_64] Loaded bzImage kernel
Failed to connect: No such device
Failed to connect: No such device

...

Issue Description
I encountered an error when trying to launch the Android Virtual Device (CVD) in AOSP. The output indicates several connection failures with the message "Failed to connect: No such device."
Questions

What could be causing this "No such device" error?
Are there any configurations I might need to check to resolve this issue?
What steps can I take to debug and fix this problem?


In my setup, I also see this message, but only until the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) service comes up with the message init: starting service 'adbd'... As such, I believe this is just a side effect of asynchronous components of the boot process. Specifically, the ADB client trying to connect to the device before the ADB daemon is running.
In answer to each of your numbered questions:

ADB client trying to connect the ADB daemon before the device is fully booted and the adbd process running.
I don't believe there are any easy configuration changes that would change this behavior.
Unless it is persisting well after the virtual device finishes booting, it isn't really a problem.

